# DynamicCastClassUnconditional with Custom Cell Class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I want to use a custom cell class which contains a textfield. But I always get the DynamicCastClassUnconditional error for each cell. How do I get rid of this error? And is my Custom Cell class correct?

Table-Class

```
import UIKit

class SettingsEndpointCreateViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cellId:String = "EndPointName";
    var cell:TextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as TextCell;


    return cell;
}

@IBAction func returnToPrevious(){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
}
```

Custom-Cell-Class

```
import UIKit

class TextCell: UITableViewCell {

var textField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    addSubview(textField)

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your custom cell class with the table view for that reuse identifier. In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
class SettingsEndpointCreateViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerClass(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EndPointName")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Also, note that the method you're using to dequeue a cell returns an optional value. You can either handle that or call the newer, non-optional returning method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextCell
```

(Finally, the reuse identifier should really be a constant set somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me why my textfield isnt showing up inside the cell?

Comment: You're adding your text field to the cell's view in `awakeFromNib`, but that only gets called when you're initializing your cell from a .nib/.xib file, which you aren't doing. Check out [this gist for how to proceed](https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/ca64e1dc4fa41adfc603).